# How to solve AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'

Tags: python, mp3, nonetype, eyed3

I'm using the eyed3 and this is a part of my long code:

```python
if new_file.exists():
            print(f'{data[i][0]} has been\033[1;32;40m successfully downloaded.\033[m  ')
            mySong = eyed3.core.load(new_file)
            print(new_file)
            print(mySong)
            if (mySong.tag == None):
                mySong.initTag()
            mySong.tag.images.set(type_=3, img_data=None ,mine_type=None,description=None,img_url=data[i][3] )
            mySong.tag.save()
```

And I'm getting this error thousands of times:

```
I Ain't Worried has been successfully downloaded.
C:\Users\elabr\Desktop\Folder\I Aint Worried.mp3
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elabr\youtube_api.py", line 60, in <module>
    if (mySong.tag == None):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

I dont't know what im doing wrong tbh and would really appreaciate some help pls guys.

Comment: From the documentation of [`eye3d.core.load`](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eyed3.html#eyed3.core.load): "_`None` is returned when the file type (i.e. mime-type) is not recognized_". And as you can see from your output, `mySong` is `None`, meaning it didn't recognize the file type of the file you passed. Though given your file is supposedly an MP3 file, I'm not sure why `load` would not recognize the file type. Do other applications recognize the MP3 file?

Comment: Yes they do. I even opened the file and had nothing wrong with it